# How to create an "expanding" menu in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, menu, customization

I need to have a menu options on my application, but the various options i have for my application are too many to fit in a screen.

What i find delicate, is what i have seen in various applications where the options are like expanding buttons, that reveal more settings when pressed.

I am attaching a picture of an "expanding" menu, before and after clicked.

[image]

[image]

As you see the options like this look much more delicate.
 Does anyone have any idea how i can implement something like that in my app?
 Is it something completely customized ?
  Is there a tutorial you are aware of , on how to succeed on such an effect?

Answer (score 0):

There are some good examples you can use for your requirements, [here](https://github.com/raihan/Drop-Down-Demo-iOS) and [here](https://github.com/katokichisoft/KSPopoverView), with some modifications of course.

Comment: Hmm , not what i am looking for. I would need something simpler , without "graphics" like that.

Comment: Hence I mentioned "modifications" like that.

Comment: You can modify anything to another thing. The point is to be as close as possible. This seems to be a lot of unnecessary work.

Comment: That "graphics" is only an animation. You could remove it to your requirement. But its your call. I just suggested this as it does the "expanding cell" very close to the image you have given.

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://github.com/mrdepth/tools/tree/master/CollapsableTableView

You can use this control to show and hide menu.

Comment: Thank you , but i dont know how exactly to use these 2 files. Are they implemented in a project to see how they work? The code is not commented either making it more difficult to understand. I created a new XCode project , put them inside , but the screen appears just black. Wheres the .nib file?

Comment: You will use it as you TableView instance as you did earlier and set its delegate and datasource.

Comment: I am sorry i dont follow you. What do you mean use it as a tableview instance? Is there a simple working project with this? or guide me how to create one , with simple words cause i am not so experienced in iOS.

Comment: just make it class of your tableView and use its methods to get required results.

Comment: Ok i ll try that. Just to clear something out , this will give me the effect that i show in the screenshot? Cause you are using the word tableview , and i am not interested to have an expandable table with cells. I want something like the images.

Comment: Using this tableView for this efficient and optimised. From above image it is in tableView.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use a TableView and each cell will have settings option and add and delete rows with animation on clicking the cell ;)
OR
Create different views and initially hide them and on tapping on any setting button just add those views with opening animation and set frame too.

Comment: Yes but it wont look good if all the screen is a table view. I dont want it to look like a table view , which for example has 5 cells with options and the rest of the cells blank. I would like it to appear more natural like a screen. Like the screenshot. Unless if you mean something else and i misunderstood u.